# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't work if there is only one element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="notifications-feed" class="content" data-ng-controller="feedContentCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="entry in cmsData.rss.channel.item">

            <div data-ng-bind-html="entry.description"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSON that gets read from a URL:

```
{
"rss": 
{
    "channel": 
    {
        "description": "",
        "item": 
        {
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "link": "http://foo.bar",
            "pubDate": "Friday, February 21, 2014 - 17:52",
            "title": "Server Maintenance"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "link": "http://foo.bar/alerts",
        "title": "<a href=&#039;/news&#039;>News & Updates<\/a>"
    },
}}
```

This works fine if there are more than one "item" elements. However, in this case there is only one so nothing shows up. If I just put:

```
<div data-ng-bind="cmsData.rss.channel.item.desciption"></div>
```

Then it shows up. Does ng-repeat not work when there is only one?

**Edit**: Fixed by changing the code to:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(items, item) in cmsData.rss.channel">

    <div data-ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` iterates and array. `cmsData.rss.channel.item` is not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, `ng-repeat` the way you have is for an array. Use the following syntax for objects and properties:

```
(k, v) in cmsData.rss.channel.item
```

This will iterate each key/val pair inside `cmsData.rss.channel.item`

Comment: Sometimes (quite often) there will be more than one rss.channel.item.

Comment: @ryoung -- if that's the case, `channel.item` should most definitely be an array. You can then handle empty arrays nicely.

Comment: +1 never seen that you can do iterate object properties with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can check to see if "item" is an array? I have to handle both cases. If there is only one then the "item" will not be an array. I have no control over the JSON. I.e. if item is array {use ng-repeat} else {don't use ng-repeat}

Comment: You can check with `typeof`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because in the JSON object, the "item", isn't an Array.

To fix:

```
{
"rss": 
{
    "channel": 
    {
        "description": "",
        "item": 
        [{
            "description": "blah blah blah",
            "link": "http://foo.bar",
            "pubDate": "Friday, February 21, 2014 - 17:52",
            "title": "Server Maintenance"
        }],
        "language": "en",
        "link": "http://foo.bar/alerts",
        "title": "<a href=&#039;/news&#039;>News & Updates<\/a>"
    },
}}
```

Comment: This JSON gets generated from an rss/xml feed using a Java JSONObject so I have no real control over changing the JSON to have the item as an array as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an object not an array, check the docs for using an object in ngRepeat's arguments.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

You would need `data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in cmsData.rss.channel.item`

Then you could use `<div data-ng-bind-html="value"></div>` which would list all of item's properties.