# ng-repeat: One-item-only source (XML)

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

To simplified things, I've made a mistake in my question here: 
[ng-repeat: One-item-only source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085625/ng-repeat-one-item-only-source)

So I ask here **the same question but with the real problem**:

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
$http.get("http://angularjs.uum.my/tt.xml",
                {transformResponse:function(data) {
                  // convert the data to JSON and provide
                  // it to the success function below
                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                    var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
                    return json;
                    }
                })
.success(function(response) {$scope.scrollItems3 = response.NewDataSet.Table;});

$http.get("http://angularjs.uum.my/tt2.xml",
                {transformResponse:function(data) {
                  // convert the data to JSON and provide
                  // it to the success function below
                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                    var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
                    return json;
                    }
                })
.success(function(response) {$scope.scrollItems4 = response.NewDataSet.Table;});
```

**tt.xml - have only 1 element**

http://angularjs.uum.my/app/#/timetable3

**tt2.xml - have two 2 elements**

http://angularjs.uum.my/app/#/timetable4

The problem is with page no. 1, where only one element exist, the page rendered empty list repeating x number of times (where x equal to number of child elements)

Is this known bug? How to solve this problem if the number of elements is unknown beforehand to the developer?

Unlike the previous question, here there is no array...

Please help, thanks for your time.

Comment: you have the same mistake I already answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085625/ng-repeat-one-item-only-source/27085667#27085667, that is not a bug, your json is not correct

Comment: this time it is xml file..

Comment: it does not matter if it is an xml file, the problem is that you are not returning an array, you are returning just 1 object, it is totally different an array with one object than a single object

Comment: I'm looking an anwer like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052809/angularjs-ng-repeat-doesnt-work-if-there-is-only-one-element I try the solution there, but it doesn't work for me.